# Format of Date_Trunc in SQL (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The below works:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', TIMESTAMP '2017-03-17 02:09:30')
```

But if I remove the "TIMESTAMP" part (as below) it doesn't. Why is this?

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', '2017-03-17 02:09:30')
```

From what I understand, the format should just be:

```
DATE_TRUNC('datepart', timestamp)
```

This simple format works in other situations..

Comment: You need `timestamp` to introduce a `datetime` constant.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question that is not directly related, if I am doing:

SELECT to_date ('02 Oct 2001', 'DD Mon YYYY');

How can I ensure the resulting format is in a format I specify? For example DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: DATE or TIMESTAMP values don't have a format. Any format you see is applied by the application _displaying_ those values.

Answer (score 2):

The `timestamp '2017-03-17'` is a so-called timestamp-literal. The prefix `timestamp` is what makes this a timestamp and not a char. If you just have `'2017-03-17'`, then it is a char-literal, which is not a timestamp, and `DATE_TRUNC` requires a datetime value.

Comment: I have a followup question. Can we use date_trunc for a date (not date-time) that we are trying to truncate to e.g. the start of the week? So if I have date_trunc(week, 28/10/2020)? I tried this in my SQL command line but I get error messages.

Comment: @bz_2020 Please ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`select date_trunc('week', to_date('28/10/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'))`

It will return date of monday for current week.